# How to read a file into an array on Xamerin in IOS app using StreamReader (or some other alternative)

Tags: c#, ios, arrays, xamarin, streamreader

I am trying to do what I thought would be a simple task, but can't figure it out.

I have created a new Xamerin Forms project (using *.net standard*, as sharing strategy,) and it looks like this:

[image]

I created a text file and I want to read it into an array so I can use it in my app.

I added the text file to my project (by adding it to the top project, which doesn't have an OS associated with it), here:

[image]

In my app I have the following code:

```
InitializeComponent ();

        //Define our array variable
        string[] quotations = new string[10];

        //Read the text from text file and populate array
        StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(@"Quotations.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            quotations[i] = SR.ReadLine();
        }

        Quote.Text = quotations[0];

        //Close text file
        SR.Close();
```

...

I have checked the properties for the file, and set them to 'build action: embedded resource', in the top project.

[image]

(I haven't added the file into the individual OS projects...)

When I run my application, on IOS it generates an exception, and exits the app almost as soon as it started:

`Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:`

[image]

How can I attach a file to my project, and read the contents into an array , on IOS?

Thanks

Comment: please do NOT post code as an image!

Answer (score 1):

`new StreamReader(@"Quotations.txt");` loads a file from the file system, but your data isn't *in* the file system - it is embedded in the assembly.

Embedded resources need to be accessed in a special way - in particular via `yourAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)`. Note that the *embedded* name might not be quite what you expect, so the best thing to do is to (as a quick test) use `yourAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` and write out the names that are embedded. That'll tell you the one to actually include as `resourceName`. Once you have the `Stream`, you can use a `new StreamReader(theResourceStream)` on it.

Note: the easiest way to get `yourAssembly` is something like `typeof(SomeTypeInYourAssembly).Assembly`.

Comment: @Gary you shouldn't need the assembly name - see the last line as an easy way to get your own `Assembly`

Comment: thanks, I managed to retrieve this output using GetManifestResourceNames "mscorlib.xml, collation.cjkKOlv2.bin, collation.cjkKO.bin, collation.cjkJA.bin, collation.cjkCHT.bin, collation.cjkCHS.bin, collation.tailoring.bin, collation.core.bin, charinfo.nlp, " am I heading in the right direction here would you say? I can't see anything that resembles my quotation.txt in that list

Comment: @Gary are you sure you looked in the right assembly? what type did you use to get it? that looks like mscorlib...